# combine 2 queries to get users that are my friends and have a certain name

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. Table users(user_id, name, surname) and table friends(friend_id ,user_one, user_two). Table friends helps me to keep the users that are my friends. Where user_one or user_two are the user_ids from users in my users table that are my friends (I am the $session_user_id). I have created the following 2 queries:

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT `user_id` FROM users WHERE (surname LIKE '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%') ");

$check_friend_query = mysql_query("  SELECT friends_id from friends WHERE  (user_one='$session_user_id' AND user_two ='$user_id') OR (user_one='$user_id' AND user_two='$session_user_id')   ");
```

I have a search script that I want to select all users that have name like that the users inserts in the search form and also are friend. How can I combine the above 2 queries to get the result that I want. (I mean to get for example all john Smith from my database that are also my friends)

Comment: Can you please reframe your question.Pretty confusing what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two queries by joining them together:

```
SELECT friends_id
from friends f join
     users u
     on u.user_id = f.user_one and f.user_two = $user_id or
        u.user_id = f.user_two and f.user_one = $user_id
where (u.surname LIKE '$name%' AND u.name LIKE '$surname%')
```